# Why linkedin widget on .net site renders junk characters?

Tags: c#, google-chrome, linkedin-api, encode, mojibake

We have a linkedin follow button widget on site.It works as expected in English language but when we choose location of machine (from control panel) to Sweden and set default primary language of Google chrome to 'Svenksa' it renders text with junk characters 'FÃ¶lj'.

Tried to set encoding  using meta tag but it did not work.

Scripts we use :

```
<script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="IN/FollowCompany" data-counter="right" data-id="XXXXXX"></script>
```

In English it renders normal 'FOLLOW' but in svenska it renders 'FÃ¶lj'

Comment: <script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="IN/FollowCompany" data-counter="right" data-id="XXXXX" charset="utf-8"></script>

Comment: `'FÃ¶lj'` looks Swedish to me.

Comment: Yes, It is swedish but with junk characters.

Comment: Sorry, I was just making a very poor 'English' joke.

Answer (score 0):

When I set my browser's language to Swedish and run that snippet, I find the following response inside the iframe:

```
~$ curl -v 'https://www.linkedin.com/pages-extensions/FollowCompany?id=361557' -H 'accept-language: sv' 
…
> GET /pages-extensions/FollowCompany?id=361557&counter=right HTTP/2
> Host: www.linkedin.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
> accept-language: sv
…
< HTTP/2 200 
< content-type: text/html
…
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>
…
<button class="follow-btn--no-count">Följ</button>
…
```

Since the `content-type` header in the response doesn't specify a `charset`, and there's no `<meta>` element with a charset, the browser uses the default of Latin-1, but the document is actually UTF-8.

(My terminal assumes everything is UTF-8 and so printed `Följ` instead of `FÃ¶lj`.)

You don't have a workaround in this case. You should file a bug.